# Azure Visual Studio (2012) Tools unable to load java file not found exception

Tags: java, azure, jetty

I have followed this tutorial
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dachou/archive/2010/03/21/run-java-with-jetty-in-windows-azure.aspx
but I get "file not found exception when I run the program.
I have tried many times but it does not work.
Now I have added only \app\java to the workerrole and I used this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace JettyWorkerRole
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            string response = "";

            System.IO.StreamReader sr; 

            // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
            Trace.TraceInformation("JettyWorkerRole entry point called", "Information");

            string roleRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");
            string port = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint.Port.ToString();
            string address = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint.Address.ToString();
            Trace.TraceInformation("RADICE " + roleRoot, "Information");
            Trace.TraceInformation("PORTA " + port, "Information");
            Trace.TraceInformation("INDIRIZZO " + address, "Information");
            string jreHome = roleRoot + @"\approot\app\jre7";
            Trace.TraceInformation("JAVA 7 " + jreHome, "Information");


            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = String.Format("\"{0}\\bin\\java.exe\"", jreHome);
            //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-Djetty.port={0} -Djetty.home=\"{1}\" -jar \"{1}\\start.jar\"", port, jettyHome);
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-version");
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.Start();

            sr = proc.StandardOutput;
            response = sr.ReadToEnd(); 

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

            // For information on handling configuration changes
            // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get alwais Win32 exception file not found at proc.Start(). How can I fix this and use Java (and jetty)?

Answer (score 0):

This is because *there is no JVM/JRE installed on the hosting OS* by default and the `java.exe` is not found.

There are several ways to get JVM installed on the hosted Azure machine. The one described in the blog entry you reference is just to perform a "copy"-installation by adding `jre6` folders to your Azure project. Notice, however, that the actual JRE binaries are not included into the sample project and need to be added manually along with correct setting for deployment.

Another option, as suggested in [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariok/archive/2011/01/05/deploying-java-applications-in-azure.aspx), is to put your JVM binaries to blob storage and download them on role start-up.